# brahms requiem - two pianos, 4 hands version?

Tags: piano, classical-music, accompaniment, choir

Our small church was recently bequeathed a fine 7 foot grand, which pairs incredibly nicely with our current 7 foot grand.

I’m thinking of an inaugural concert, featuring the Brahms Requiem, accompanied by two pianos, 4 hands.

IMSLP has this accompaniment, arranged by August Grüters.

Does anyone have experience with this edition, or have any pro/con suggestions or thoughts about pursuing this project to feature these two pianos?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me.  I can't think of much else to say about it.  What kinds of answers wert you hoping for?

Comment: This version of the requiem was played in 2012 on the incomplete construction site of what would become the Hamburg Elbphilharmonie (https://www.elbphilharmonie.de/de/archiv/human-requiem/3445). By all accounts, it was an amazingly memorable event.

Comment: @KilianFoth that page indicates that the version performed was the version for (one) piano four hands, which is the composer's own, not the arrangement for two pianos four hands by Grüters.

Comment: Since there is a canonical 4-hands arrangement by Brahms himself I think this should work quite well, with maybe more power in the forte passages and improved independence of voices. But why don’t you simply look for a performance like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gx3FxPwhFJ4 and checkout if it suits you taste and is technically viable.

Comment: Welcome! Please read about [how to make sure questions can have specific answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Stack exchange, unlike many forums, isn't geared for "everyone say everything you can think of on a given topic; discuss." I suggest editing the question if you already have specific concerns in mind.

Comment: @Lazy the point of the concert is to mark the acquisition of a second piano that pairs well with the existing piano.  A piece for one piano four hands does not serve the purpose.

Comment: @phoog I suppose you misunderstood what I said? I was saying that since there is quite a nice 4-hand arrangement by the composer this two piano version should probably turn out quite well, as the arranger had access to Brahm’s own pianistic vision of this.

Comment: @Lazy yes, I did misunderstand.  Thanks for clarifying.